# How can I display live feed from social media (Twitter & Instagram) in Typescript using the Zappar platform

Tags: ajax, typescript, request, instagram, augmented-reality

I found out that it should be possible as Zappar supports Ajax calls. But I don't know how to make it work. I already tried some JavaScript to pull the Instagram feed, but the script didn't understand the "document." statement. Don't know how to bypass that.

This is an example from the Zappar platform:

```
// Parameters to configure the AJAX request
const ajaxParameters : Z.Ajax.Parameters = {
    url: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wizcontent/test/zappar.json",
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 3000
};

// Perform the AJAX request
Z.ajax(ajaxParameters, (statusCode, data, request) => {

    if (statusCode === 0) {
        locationText.text("Unable to connect - check network connection.");
        return;
    }

    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300) {
        locationText.text("HTTP request failed: " + statusCode);
        return;
    }

    // Attempt to parse the data returned from the AJAX request as JSON
    let parsedData;
    try {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
        parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        locationText.text("Unable to parse JSON: " + e);
        return;
    }

    // Check the data is as expected and display it
    if (parsedData.company) {
        locationText.text(parsedData.headOffice);
    } else {
        locationText.text("Unexpected response from API");
    }

});
```